# Is it possible to include PHP code that is in memory?

Tags: php, include, php-5.3

Say I have a variable containing PHP code, can I include its content as if it was a normal PHP file ?

For example, the PHP code could be a class declaration.

Comment: Seriously reconsider why this is necessary. Chances are, there are far better ways to accomplish your goal.

Comment: My goal is to have fun. I won't reconsider that sir ! ;p

Comment: If your goal is to have fun pulling your hair out because all your files were deleted, then have to it!

Comment: I don't know, where your "variable [..] PHP code" comes from, but I suspect, that it comes from unsecure source (because nearly every variable code can be treated as unsecure).

Comment: @KingCrunch Your suspicions are wrong. I'm just doing that for fun, I'm not going to use that in any way on a production environment. And I'm **most certainly not** using code from a user input or any other insecure source...

Comment: So, Lisp guys are welcomed to treat variables as code, but PHP guys be damned if they do so? Code generation at runtime is not inherently bad, we use it all the time with reflection etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
eval($your_variable);
```

Be aware about security holes!This is very dangerous and should NOT be based on user's input !

Comment: Yes I know the dangers of eval, I will be careful. Though, I wonder: is `eval` exactly like including a file ??

Comment: @Matthieu: No, but looking at the manual is slightly faster, than asking here about the meaning of language features ;) `eval()` evaluates code from a string. `include $filename` is equivalent (not identical!) to `eval(file_get_contents($filename))`, but not the other way round.

Comment: @KingCrunch thanks for reading the manual for me ;). I understand I could have checked, but since I need to accept an answer (that may be useful to other crazies like me), I'd rather have all the elements of the solution here (and I didn't think that would be on the manual honestly).

Comment: You got it, I was just giving it some more time in case of any other possible answer. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You don't have a variable containing php code. You have a string.
You can execute a string as php with the evil [eval](http://php.net/eval) function, but **puppies AND kittens** will die!

Comment: Added kittens, poor poor kittens!

Comment: I don't care for the kittens, though I'll watch out for the puppies

Comment: Without kittens (which grow into cats), there'd be no Interwebitubes. The Sprint commercials tell me so.

Comment: """You don't have a variable containing php code. You have a string. """ Bzzzt, wrong. He *has* a variable containing php code. That's what matters to him, not that it's a string.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `eval` to evaluate any code that you have in your string, however it is evil. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Can we be spared the "eval is evil" old wives tales?

Comment: Now I can confess, I have suffered from several maledictions since I've used eval. Thank you for bringing balance into the world @foljs ;)